# How can I get my css gradient to work in IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

http://www.10thplanetjjchicago.com/

Everything seems to work fine in Firefox/Chrome/Safari/Opera. But I can't seem to get my content div to display correctly in Internet Explorer.  The gradient just doesn't display or cuts off - yet the text and content will display.  I've been playing around with reordering elements and whatnot but I can't figure it out :/

To see my code just View Source.

CSS is minimized so here's the CSS:

```
body {
    background: #080808;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#bg {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#232323,#080808);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#232323,#080808);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#232323,#080808);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#232323,#080808);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#232323,#080808);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#232323),to(#080808));
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#232323',endColorstr='#080808',GradientType=0);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 531px;
}
.header {
    background: #282828;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#040404,#282828);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#040404,#282828);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#040404,#282828);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#040404,#282828);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#040404,#282828);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#040404),to(#282828));
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#040404',endColorstr='#282828',GradientType=0);
    border: 1px solid #7ba145;
    border-top-left-radius: 9px;
    border-top-right-radius: 9px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 900px;
    height: 85px;
}
.logo {
    border: 0;
    opacity: .9;
}
.logo: hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
.nav-left,.nav-right {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 338px;
    word-spacing: 40px;
}
.nav-middle {
    float: left;
    margin-top: -48px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
a.nav-link: link,a.nav-link: visited {
    color: #b5ed46;
    font: 18px impact,tahoma,arial;
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity: .8;
}
a.nav-link: hover {
    color: #eee;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #96c34b;
    opacity: .9;
}
.background {
    text-align: center;
}
.bg-img {
    border-left: 1px solid #96c34b;
    border-right: 1px solid #96c34b;
    margin-top: -50px;
    opacity: .9;
}
.bg-img: hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
.main {
    background: #303030;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#171717,#303030);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#171717,#303030);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#171717,#303030);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#171717,#303030);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#171717,#303030);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#171717),to(#303030));
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#171717',endColorstr='#303030',GradientType=0);
    border: 1px solid #96c34b;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 9px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 9px;
    margin: -4px auto;
    padding: 32px 32px 16px;
    width: 836px;
}
.content {
    float: left;
}
.title {
    color: #96c34b;
    font: 18px impact,tahoma,arial;
    opacity: .9;
    word-spacing: 3px;
}
.title: hover {
    color: #eee;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #96c34b;
}
a: link,a: visited {
    color: #b5ed46;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a: hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
p {
    color: #eee;
    font: 12px tahoma,arial;
    line-height: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    opacity: .8;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 550px;
    word-spacing: 3px;
}
.side-panel {
    color: #efefef;
    float: right;
    font: 11px tahoma,arial;
    line-height: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    opacity: .9;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 250px;
    word-spacing: 3px;
}
p: hover {
    color: #efefef;
    opacity: .9;
}
.side-panel: hover {
    color: #fff;
}
.copyright {
    color: #ddd;
    clear: both;
    font: 10px tahoma,arial;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: .8;
}
.copyright: hover {
    color: #efefef;
    opacity: .9;
}
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you could make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demo (something people can easily edit and experiment with).

Answer (score -2):

Your CSS is very difficult to read (try new lines at least when things get long), but at 1st glance it looks like you covered all the bases.  Here's a sample gradient (higher contrast grey AKA black glass) you can take a look at:

```
background: #959595; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #959595 0%, #0d0d0d 46%, #010101 50%, #0a0a0a 53%, #4e4e4e 76%, #383838 87%, #1b1b1b 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#959595), color-stop(46%,#0d0d0d), color-stop(50%,#010101), color-stop(53%,#0a0a0a), color-stop(76%,#4e4e4e), color-stop(87%,#383838), color-stop(100%,#1b1b1b)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #959595 0%,#0d0d0d 46%,#010101 50%,#0a0a0a 53%,#4e4e4e 76%,#383838 87%,#1b1b1b 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #959595 0%,#0d0d0d 46%,#010101 50%,#0a0a0a 53%,#4e4e4e 76%,#383838 87%,#1b1b1b 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #959595 0%,#0d0d0d 46%,#010101 50%,#0a0a0a 53%,#4e4e4e 76%,#383838 87%,#1b1b1b 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #959595 0%,#0d0d0d 46%,#010101 50%,#0a0a0a 53%,#4e4e4e 76%,#383838 87%,#1b1b1b 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#959595', endColorstr='#1b1b1b',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

I don't try to hand code gradients because it always turns out to be a pain to change all those values at the same time.  Try this: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ (which is where I stole that gradient from)

Comment: -ms- prefix version is not needed. No released version of IE ever used it. IE10 will use the unprefixed standard and final syntax. -ms- was only needed for platform previews of IE10.

Comment: Ok, maybe I should have been more specific. I don't need help generating the gradient - that I already have.  I have a display issue where IE is cutting off part of the gradient in the content div.  If you notice, you can see the the gradients working on the background and in the nav bar but just not in the content div.

Comment: readability is relative. may not be easy for you, but its not your code.

Comment: Thanks for the re-post, was able to check it in a few minutes.  I'm not saying code needs to be readable on the site, but that posts here should include something readable for those helping out.  I was under the impression IE didn't load any gradient, so that changes things.  Is it all versions of IE or any version in particular?  I can test 8 and 10....

Comment: I'm looking at it with IE 9 and it's cutting off still :/

Comment: In IE10 the CSS is broken, in IE8 for some reason the page ended right under the large image at the top.  I'm not seeing anything that stands out in the definitions of the class .main so I'm pretty much stumped as well.