# Repeating gradient doesn't work in IE7 and IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I'm trying to display a repeating gradient in my website with IE7 and IE8. I'm using the following code:

```
/* start code as CSS rules applied */

background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-color: white;
background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(left, #CCD1D5, white, #CCD1D5, white, #CCD1D5, white, #CCD1D5, white 943px);
background: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(left, #CCD1D5, white, #CCD1D5, white, #CCD1D5, white, #CCD1D5, white 943px);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(180deg,#CCD1D5,white, #CCD1D5,white,#CCD1D5,white 943px);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#CCD1D5', endColorstr='white',GradientType=1);

/* end code as CSS rules applied */
```

It's working in Opera, Chrome, Firefox, IE9, and IE10, but I need it to work in IE7 and IE8 too.

Comment: older IE has problems with gradients... refer http://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/  and http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients

Comment: possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16471712/how-can-i-get-my-css-gradient-to-work-in-ie

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get my CSS linear gradient to work in IE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924632/how-do-i-get-my-css-linear-gradient-to-work-in-ie)

Comment: This question is not duplicate, I'm new an user in stackoverflow.com, thanks for you help, I'm understanding that IE7 and IE8 not work with  the linear repeating gradient css effect.

Comment: You are welcome. No problem... caniuse.com is a good source to find what is compatible to various browsers and such